# The counterpart to Challenger (name for person who accepts someone's challenge, e.g. for a duel)

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

When person A challenges person B (say, to a duel), how would you call person B, accepting the challenge (and specifically in dueling, setting the terms like choice of time, place and weapon.)

I tried to look for antonyms to Challenger, but I only found words describing people refusing challenges, shying from it, avoiding, or at best generic 'opponent' 'competitor'. Maybe there is no such word, although I'd think with language of country with a long-tradition of dueling, I'd believe this position should have a name.

Answer (score 2):

The Code Duello uses the word "Challenged", as a noun.

Comment: If you want a reference: https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/americanexperience/features/duel-code-duello-rules-dueling/